# Is there a way to use trapezoid method to get an aproximation of this integral?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The integral is:
$$I=\int_0^1x\ln x\ dx$$
I know what to do with improper integrals, for example when the limits are 0 and infinite, just do a change of variables $x = \frac{1}{t}$, so the new limits are 0 and 1, but I'm clueless of what to do here, please help.

Comment: This is not an improper integral.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that I know how to deal with some rare cases when using numerical methods to aproximate integrals, for example improper integrals, but I don't know how what to do when the function is undefined.

Comment: It's not undefined, is it ?

Comment: When you apply trapezoid rule you should have to evaluate 0 * ln(0), it's undefined for me.

Comment: Just define it to be $0$.

Comment: And why I can say that 0 * ln(0) = 0? I don't understand..., if it were 0 * a function that is undefined but bounded I would say "Ok, it's 0", but in thiscase I don't see it so clearly.

Comment: By using the limit you just make the function continuous. Technically speaking you could use any value as the continuous integral is not influenced by a zero-measure set, but that would impair the accuracy of the trapezoid approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Integration:

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 x\ln x dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln x|_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 x dx=0-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{4}$

For Trapezoid rule see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule .